# Get the http headers from current request in PHP

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers

Is it possible to get the http headers of the current request with PHP? I am **not** using Apache as the web-server, but using nginx.

I tried using `getallheaders()` but I am getting `Call to undefined function getallheaders()`.

Comment: as you can see in my answer you can still use getallheaders()

Comment: Go vote here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62596

Answer (score 50):

Taken from the documentation someone wrote a [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#84262)...

```
if (!function_exists('getallheaders')) 
{ 
    function getallheaders() 
    { 
       $headers = array (); 
       foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) 
       { 
           if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') 
           { 
               $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value; 
           } 
       } 
       return $headers; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But could you explain what is the purpose of `ucwords` and `strtolower` in that function ? Is it necessary ?

Comment: A bug in this function is that uppercase headers such as "DNT" (Do Not Track) will become "Dnt" - which is NOT the case of native getallheaders()

Comment: The "Authorization" didn't appear with this function... Any idea ?

Answer (score 27):

Improved @Layke his function, making it a bit more secure to use it:

```
if (!function_exists('getallheaders'))  {
    function getallheaders()
    {
        if (!is_array($_SERVER)) {
            return array();
        }

        $headers = array();
        foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
                $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $headers;
    }
}
```

(wished I could just add this as a comment to his answer but still building on that reputation thingy -- one of my first replies)

Answer (score 4):

This issue was finally addressed in PHP 7.3.0, check [release notes](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.3.0).

> Fixed bug [#62596](http://bugs.php.net/62596) (getallheaders() missing with PHP-FPM).

Comment: Can you elaborate what this means? (Answers should be self contained, see for example "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Also, links are often broken after some time ...

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade your server to PHP 5.4 thereby giving you access to [getallheaders()](http://php.net/getallheaders) via fastcgi or simply parse what you need out of $_SERVER with a `foreach` loop and a little regex.

Comment: Does `nginx` always run on FastCGI? Is that why `getallheaders()` doesn't work under PHP 5.3?

Comment: @BenHarold See changelog of [getallheaders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php): _5.4: This function became available under FastCGI. Previously, it was supported only when PHP was installed as an Apache module._

Comment: @FredWuerges I did read the changelog. That's why I asked the questions. To word it a little better: Does nginx always use FastCGI, and is that why `getallheaders()` doesn't work when using PHP 5.3 or older with nginx? Does this mean that both `getallheaders()` and `apache_request_headers()` work when using PHP 5.4 and nginx?

Comment: @BenHarold Now it's clear. If we follow the premise of the changelog, we conclude that the wheel always nginx with FastCGI, if PHP is in 5.4 or higher, will work. Thus, if PHP is in 5.3 will not run on nginx.

Comment: This should be marked as correct. On 5.4, just do $headers = getallheaders(); if ($token = $headers['Authorization']) {/*check token*/} else {/*Not authed*/}. Very simple.

Comment: This does not work on nginx still, getallheaders is filed under apache functions in the PHP doc since it is Apache only as confirmed on php 5.5 and nginx

Comment: Currently on PHP7 getallheaders does not work on nginx under FastCGI

Answer (score 3):

**Combined getallheaders() + apache_request_headers() for nginx**

```
    function get_nginx_headers($function_name='getallheaders'){

        $all_headers=array();

        if(function_exists($function_name)){ 

            $all_headers=$function_name();
        }
        else{

            foreach($_SERVER as $name => $value){

                if(substr($name,0,5)=='HTTP_'){

                    $name=substr($name,5);
                    $name=str_replace('_',' ',$name);
                    $name=strtolower($name);
                    $name=ucwords($name);
                    $name=str_replace(' ', '-', $name);

                    $all_headers[$name] = $value; 
                }
                elseif($function_name=='apache_request_headers'){

                    $all_headers[$name] = $value; 
                }
            }
        }


        return $all_headers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php 

print_r(
  array_intersect_key(
    $_SERVER,
    array_flip(
      preg_grep(
        '/^HTTP_/', 
        array_keys($_SERVER),
        0
      )
    )
  )
);
```