# Retrieveing curl header values in php

Tags: php, curl, header

am hitting an api call using curl and I am sending "X_ACCESSKEY" as header.
Following is my code

```
    $url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/getheader";
         $data=array();
        $data = json_encode($data);            
        $ch = curl_init($url);            
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
        $headers = array('Content-Type:application/json','X_ACCESSKEY: 1234');
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        # Return response instead of printing.
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        # Send request.
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Now I want to get the "X_ACCESSKEY" header value in "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/getheader"

Comment: Can you clarify your questions a bit more?

Comment: I am sending header values using curl to an api, I need to get those header values in the api file.   HEADERS : $headers = array('Content-Type:application/json','X_ACCESSKEY: 1234');  I want to get ACCESSKEY as "1234" in my api file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `getallheaders()`, this function is an alias for `apache_request_headers()`, but it also appears to work on other webservers.

Documentation is listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

You may also look at this question: [Get the http headers from current request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224615/get-the-http-headers-from-current-request-in-php)

Comment: It is working for same server and it is not working for different server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apache_request_headers](https://php.net/manual/de/function.apache-request-headers.php) to receive all headers sent by the client.

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();
print_r($headers);
echo $headers["X_ACCESSKEY"];
```

Comment: I am not using apache server and i am using nginx, does it work for me?

Comment: getting an error that undefined function apache_request_headers()