# Patreon - Don't get HTTP query parameters after "Become a Patron" button

Tags: php, oauth, patreon

I'm trying to implement the "Become a Patron" button on my PHP website ([documentation](https://www.patreon.com/platform/documentation/widgets)).

As aditional parameters for the "Redirect URL" i set a JOB and a USERID, so my Redirect URL looks something like this:

```
https://www.MYWEBSITE.TLD/?job=patreon&userid=MYUSERID
```

I need the "job" to know that the redirect is from Patreon and the "userid" so i can give a patron the reward.

The HTML generated code from Patreon looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.patreon.com/bePatron?u=PATREONUSERID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.MYWEBSITE.TLD%2F%3Fjob%3Dpatreon%26userid%3DMYUSERID">
<img height="40" width="204" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/widget-images/become-patron-widget-medium%402x.png">
</a>
```

After a patron clicks the link and the pledge is set he will be redirected as provided, but all i get in the request is the job and the userid.

The documentation said:

> If you'd like to check how much they pledged, and if that pledge was new or just an update to an old pledge, you can check the HTTP query parameters in our redirect request.

So i'm asking: Where are the "amount_cents" and "action" parameters?

I've checked all the recived HEADER informations ([How to handle received HTTP Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688137/how-to-handle-received-http-header/35688215#35688215)), but all I get from $_REQUEST is:

```
Array
(
    [job] => patreon
    [userid] => MYUSERID
)
Array
(
    [job] => patreon
)
```

Also i can't find anything in $_SERVER.

Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'll contact Patreon and ask if it's something on their side.

Comment: i've done that before, but the answer i got was like "i asked the developers and it seems not be a part of patreon any more and not will be". So i switched to another platform.

Comment: then who did you contact? When I emailed them I received a response saying it was a bug on their end and that they fixed it. Though it seems that they did another update now, and the documentation is now linking to https://www.patreon.com/dashboard/widgets so I don't think it still works. Either way, I added a log in with Patreon button to find out how much a user pledged.