# How can i mock a php function when i am not using namespaces and also phpunit

Tags: php, function, mocking, phpunit

I am writing tests for a php software and i would like to know how can i mock a function (no from a class, but from a file full of functions).
This function call to a build-in php function "getallheaders" but how i am using phpunit to reach that function there is no such header in the request so as a consecuence i get "Error: Call to undefined function getallheaders()".

How can i avoid that from phpunit? 
Remember, there is no namespaces in this software and also this particular function doesn´t belong to a class, belong to a script full of functions.

I will appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tcz/phpunit-mockfunction if you actually have to mock built in functions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224615/get-the-http-headers-from-current-request-in-php if your only issue is `getallheaders` being undefined